# Ncurses and turning off input receiving

Tags: c, input, ncurses

At the beginning of launching process of my program, there is a kind of short intro, in which chars are moving, box is slowly appearing, etc. etc. After that, the proper function is activating and it is waiting for user's input (`getstr(prompt);`). However, if I press any key while the intro is loading, the input is automaticaly conveyed to prompt string, which is not desirable. How to turn off reading from input till just a line before `getstr(prompt);` and then activate it? Or maybe there's a different way to approach this problem? My idea was to use a blocking function like this (not sure it would even work):

```
timeout (1);
while (intro == 1)
{
   continue;
}
timeout (-1);
```

But I think that checking this argument all the time is not an elegant way of dealing with problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer you want is flushinp().

From the manual page

> The  flushinp  routine throws away any typeahead that has been typed
>   by the user and has not yet been read by the program.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/flushinp.3x.html

Here is an example that might fit your usage

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>

void atexit_cb(void) {
    endwin();
}

int main(void)
{
    // initialize curses
    initscr();
    raw();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();
    nodelay(stdscr, FALSE);
    atexit(atexit_cb);

    // show an intro for 3 seconds
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        mvprintw(i, 0, "...Intro text...");
        refresh();
        napms(1000);
        move(i, 0);
        clrtoeol();
    }

    // flush typeahead
    flushinp();

    // now get some new input
    printw("Press a key...");
    echo();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This simple command meets my requirements. Added to my 'useful-commands-list' ;] Thanks!